# How can i burn the tokens i create with eosio.token

Tags: smart-contract, token-distribution

I want to burn the tokens i created for some reasons, I found the method "retire" in eosio.token. But, this method only change the supply of the token, the maximum supply is still the same as it is originally.

```
 {   "rows": [{
       "supply": "9000000000.0000 SYS",
       "max_supply": "**10000000000.0000** SYS",
       "issuer": "eosio"
     }   ],   "more": false 
 }
```

So, Is there any other method for that ?

Comment: If you want to change the max_supply you can use `burntoken` action available in eosio.token.cpp. You can also play around this action according to your usecase, I hope this may help..

Comment: The max supply is there for limiting the token created, e.g. guaranteeing users of the token that no more than X will ever be created from inflation etc. Please reconsider your strategy of mutating max_supply because I believe this is out of standard practice, otherwise could you further explain your strategy and why such a thing would be warranted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of `eosio.token` doesn't support `burn` you describe. Add next code block to your token contract.

```
void token::burn( const asset& quantity, const string& memo ) {
   auto sym = quantity.symbol;
   check( sym.is_valid(), "invalid symbol name" );
   check( memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes" );

   stats statstable( get_self(), sym.code().raw() );
   auto existing = statstable.find( sym.code().raw() );
   check( existing != statstable.end(), "token with symbol does not exist" );
   const auto& st = *existing;

   require_auth( st.issuer );
   check( quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity" );
   check( quantity.amount > 0, "must burn positive quantity" );

   check( quantity.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch" );

   statstable.modify( st, same_payer, [&]( auto& s ) {
      s.supply -= quantity;
      s.max_supply -= quantity; // this line is added compared to `token::retire`
   });

   sub_balance( st.issuer, quantity );
}
```

Comment: conr2d's solution does not actually burn tokens I'm afraid. It simply reduces the supply/max_supply numbers and won't help making already circulating tokens disappear.

Comment: @user3883778 This `burn` action is designed to be executed by token issuer. It reduces supply/max_supply and also reduces token issuer's balance. (You can find `sub_balance(st.issuer, quantity);` at the last part of code.

Comment: If you want to make any token owner "burn" token, add `name owner` as the first parameter of action, check authorization of `owner` and sub_balance from owner, not issuer.